# Rounding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a simple conversion, and I want to round the number of converting an inch to centimeters. 1 inch is basically 2.54 CM, but if we round it up it would be 3. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```js
$("#ConvertInchCm").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var val = $('#value').text()
    if(($(this).text() == "Convert to CM"))
    {
         $("#value").text(val*2.54);
         Math.round($(val).text());
         $(this).text("Convert to Inches"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#value").text(val/2.54);
        $(this).text("Convert to CM");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ConvertInchCm">Convert to CM</button>
<div id="value">1</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: `Math.round($(val).text());` wut... `val` is a string...

Comment: ...and `Math.round` doesn't modify its argument, it *returns* the rounded value. So you need to do something with that...

Comment: @KevinB `Math.round` works with strings, as bad as an idea as it may be.

Comment: Wow, this is so wrong in so many aspects.

Comment: @Santi It's a terrible idea to use variable coersion with math in javascript.

Comment: I don't dispute that it's a horrible idea. I'm simply saying that it works.

Comment: The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: @Santi i'm sure it does, but `$("3462").text()` isn't going to give anything useful for rounding.

Comment: Facepalm. I thought you were noting the rounding of a string, hadn't noticed that the selector was `val`. That being said, with the rest of this code I wouldn't be surprised if perhaps there were some `<3462></3462>` elements on the page :)

Comment: For the OP: it should be `$("#value").text(Math.round(val*2.54));`, but maybe someone else will find the "courage" to actually answer :P. Not sure why you don't want to allow decimals in the `cm` unit, but do allow them for inches. Certainly in the metric system, *decimals* are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="ConvertInchCm">Convert to CM</button>
<input type="text" id="value" />
<br />
<p></p>
```

JS:

```
/**
 * @param  float  the number to round
 * @param  int  the number of decimal places to allow
 */
function roundNumber( rnum, rlength ){
  var newnumber = Math.round(rnum*Math.pow(10,rlength))/Math.pow(10,rlength);
  return parseFloat(newnumber);
}

/**
 * @param  float  the number to convert
 * @param  string  either "cm" or "in"
 * @param  int  the number of decimal places to allow
 */
function convertInchCm( num, convertTo, decimalPlaces ){
  var converted = convertTo == 'cm'
    ? parseFloat( num ) * 2.54
    : parseFloat( num ) / 2.54;
  return roundNumber( converted, decimalPlaces );
}

$("#ConvertInchCm").click(function(){
  var num = convertInchCm( $('#value').val(), 'cm', 1 );
  $('p').text( num );
});
```

Notice that I made it so you can select how many decimal places are allowed.

See it live on CodePen: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/prKzWX